# Yosemite auto creates multiple desktops (spaces) on main monitor

Tags: macos, display, desktop, mission-control

Since upgrading to Yosemite I've been having issue with OS X creating additional desktops on my main monitor for no apparent reason. I usually have 3 different desktops setup on my main monitor and just one on my second monitor. By the end of the day, OS X will usually have created 2-3 extra desktops automatically.

I can't find any setting or shortcut that might be causing this to happen. There also doesn't seem to be any reason for it since it can happen as soon as I boot up my computer.

Is there a way to set a maximum number of desktops so I can prevent this from happening?

Image from related question - [Why does Mac Yosemite open dozens and dozens of empty desktops?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178082/why-does-mac-yosemite-open-dozens-and-dozens-of-empty-desktops?lq=1)
[image]

Comment: So you're saying that in Mission Control, you created 3 spaces on your main monitor, and by the end of the day, or even as soon as you boot your computer, there are 2-3 extras that appear in Mission Control? What happens if you remove them from Mission Control?

Comment: fullscreened apps create their own space [messing up any Space-specific key commands too] but they should vanish if the app is quit or windowed.

Comment: @tubedogg, yes extra workspaces just show up by the end of the day. I can close the workspaces, but they will just show up again eventually.

Tetsujin, I'm not using any apps in full screen so I wouldn't expect the extra spaces to be created

Comment: Sorry I do not have an answer to your issue. Wanted to comment on what you said "(I've frankly never understood the point of virtual desktops anyway.)" That's fine however I've been using virtual Desktops since their inception, long before Apple had them, and I wouldn't want to work without them.  They are especially handy to group/separate various activities as one preforms high-level multitasking.  I always have no less the three primary virtual Desktop going as well as a couple full screen apps, more as the degree of multitasking requires.  Wouldn't want to live without them! :)

Comment: Do the extra Spaces appear when you disconnect your external monitors? I believe I have noticed this in the past when I have a window on a secondary monitor, and then unplug the external monitor, forcing that space to be added to those already present on the internal monitor.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: It happens to me too; I can reach 26 desktops on the main monitor, if I don't remove them.

Comment: Any update on this? I have the exact same behavior and it is a pain, a real pain. Main monitor creates extra spaces and the secondary one loses them.

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure out what the issue is here. I've tried disabling different startup programs and making sure all programs are closed before shutdown but nothing makes a difference

Comment: Apparently this is a bug that goes back further than Yosemite. Here's another question here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178082/why-does-mac-yosemite-open-dozens-and-dozens-of-empty-desktops . The suggestion of reporting the bug is probably the best thing to do: http://www.apple.com/feedback/ (or use the Feedback Assistant app if you have it installed).

Comment: Same here, I think it happens when you go fullscreen with an app and then exit fullscreen mode. The empty space doesn't get deleted.

Comment: Are you connecting and disconnecting your external display throughout the day?

Comment: @jason are you still having the same issue after updating to 10.10.4?

Comment: Similar issue reported [Insanelymac forum](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/302095-mission-control-add-desktop-every-reboot/?p=2079309) the partial answer was "To solve this simply move the MenuBar in Monitor Arrangement to IGPU and no more multiple Desktop spaces."

Comment: Try disabling "Displays have separate spaces" in System Prefs > Mission Control.  It might be related to connecting and reconnecting (or sleeping) the secondary display.

Comment: When i create additional desktop spaces on my additional monitor and unplug it from my Macbook Air, those additional spaces on the monitor are instantly migrated to the Macbook. I think your experiencing a similar problem. 
If one of your monitors are either unplugged, disconnected or generally considered dead to your mac, than that may explain the additional spaces appearing.

Comment: Just so we can be sure about whats going on, press f3, move your mouse to the top of the screen, take a screenshot (Command + Shift + 3), and add it to your post.

Answer (score 5):

It has to do with the 'separate space' feature for external displays Apple introduced in OS X 10.10 Yosemite: If the setting "Displays have separate Spaces" in System Preferences -> Mission Control is activated (see https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18809?locale=en_US), every time you hook up a display a new space will be created for that display. After you pull the plug, OS X will not delete that created space, hence accumulating lots of spaces over time.

If you don't activate the option, you're external display will behave like before 10.10: only *one* menu bar on the main screen etc.

Comment: Huh. When I plug my external monitor back in, it reuses its old spaces.

Comment: I guess then it is fixed by now.

Answer (score 1):

It is not normal behaviour to have multiple (in your case dozens) of extra Spaces being created via Mission Control.

I looked at System Preferences >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts >> Mission Control, but there is no shortcut for creating a new Space. As such, it wouldn't be that you are inadvertently creating Spaces using a shortcut.

Now, when you go full-screen with an application (e.g., Safari), then that window will become its own Space. However, when the window is closed, or restored to its original size, it will return to its original Space.

Considering your situation, I would [submit the issue as a bug](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) that Apple needs to address.

Answer (score 1):

It does very much sound like you've made the application "full screen". These are given their own desktop space. If you're using a trackpad, use three fingers to scroll up or down (I'm not on my MBP right now) and you'll see them all there.

If they're your full screen apps, make them NOT full screen.