# Removing multiple desktops at once in mission control

Tags: desktop, mission-control

I tried switching desktops, but the animation was frozen and rendered the system unusable for about a minute or so... I realized I currently have 179 desktops open somehow in mission control which is probably slowing it down... Is there an easy way to close them all at once with having to individually click x on all of them?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the com.apple.spaces in the ~/Library/Prefences

Comment: Not a duplicate, but this question showed the same issue, without finding an underlying cause or cure - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178082/why-does-mac-yosemite-open-dozens-and-dozens-of-empty-desktops

Comment: @IronCraftMan I just tried rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist* no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to hold option and click all the X's in about a minute or so, pretty hard to do with a trackpad but easy enough with a mouse.