# Yosemite keeps adding Spaces without apparent input

Tags: macos, spaces

I am using a Mac Mini with Yosemite, and I noticed that the Spaces desktops keep increasing. I delete them to keep one desktop for each of the monitors I am using, and I end up with 26 of them on the main monitor.

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: This was asked before, but got no meaningful replies - so, just as a ref - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157540/yosemite-auto-creates-multiple-desktops-spaces-on-main-monitor?rq=1

Comment: Ops, I will delete this, then. It's the same question as mine, even if it was asked earlier. Maybe, this question will put in evidence the other question.

Comment: I'd leave yours in place, at least for now - just in case it attracts a good answer. If it does, the other could be marked as dupe of this.

Comment: Same problem here. I think it happens when you go fullscreen with any app. Closing fullscreen mode doesn't remove the Space.

Comment: @PietBinnenbocht I don't use applications in full screen mode; maybe I turned one to full screen a couple of applications, but the desktops keep increasing.

Comment: Perhaps you full-screened a youtube or VLC video? That also seems to have the same effect.