# How to preserve wallpaper on secondary monitor after reboot

Tags: macos, display, mission-control

This problem began when I upgraded to Yosemite.  I have two monitors connected to my Mac Pro.  Primary monitor uses default wallpaper, and secondary monitor uses a different wallpaper (solid gray).  Every time I reboot the system, the secondary monitor reverts to the default wallpaper, and Mission Control shows an additional "desktop" on the primary monitor, with a solid gray wallpaper.
After rebooting many times, the list of desktops on the primary monitor grows quite long if I don't delete them manually.

I have read a tip to fix this behavior by disabling this feature in Sys Prefs, but I don't want to do that.

[image]

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157540/yosemite-auto-creates-multiple-desktops-spaces-on-main-monitor for perhaps some ideas, though no real answer

Answer (score 1):

Cross your fingers and stand on one leg.

More seriously, you probably need to delete related plists.

Try deleting this:

```
/Users/<your name>/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db
```