# Mac shifts desktops on maximizing

Tags: macos

Before maximizing an app (like google chrome for example)
[image]

After maximizing google chrome:[image]

Why did it shift desktops? Its somewhat irritating when I use multiple desktops and an empty one is created in between. How can I turn this feature off?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yosemite auto creates multiple desktops (spaces) on main monitor](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157540/yosemite-auto-creates-multiple-desktops-spaces-on-main-monitor)

Comment: I don't get the problem. When you full-screen an app, it gets its own space.

Comment: Not a duplicate. macOS is functioning as intended, as the answer below explains, unlike the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're simply confused as how to operate the system properly. When you think you're "maximizing" the window, you're really full-screening the application.

In order to "maximize" the window, you'll need to hold down the Alt-key while clicking the green "+" button in the top left corner of the Chrome window.

You can also maximize windows through other means - such as through an application such as SizeUp! or similar.